# reprex and html tables not formatting in stackoverflow

Tags: r, gt, reprex

The output from the `reprex` package involving html tables don't format correctly when pasting into stackoverflow.  Is there an extra step I have to take?

Here's an example.  This command sends the character data to the clipboard.

```r
reprex::reprex({
  gt::gt(head(iris))
})
```

When I paste it to stackoverflow, I see this preview (a mess of raw html instead of a formatted table).

[image: reprex output]

Comment: What exactly do you want the output to be? Is there a reason you are trying to use `gt` in the reproducible example? Is that where the error occurs or are you just trying to format the output?

Comment: I want the output to be an html table.  There is no reason for `gt` in particular - the same problem exists for `kable` tables.  There is no R error that occurs.  The issue is that the output does not format correctly in stackoverflow.

Comment: Stack Overflow doens't support gt tables or kable tables. Those use HTML or latex for formatting. It has it's own syntax for tables. You can use `repex(..., venue="so")`. It's almost always better to share a `dput()` of your data than a crazy formatted version of it when asking for help.

Comment: I don't need a `dput`, because my data is `iris`.

Comment: I tried this command as you suggested `reprex::reprex({gt::gt(head(iris))}, venue = "so")`, but I receive a message "The Stack Overflow venue "so" is an alias for the default GitHub venue "gh". There is no need to specify the venue.", and I experience the same issue when pasting into stackoverflow.